# Hover Problem in CSS -- Overwriting

Tags: html, css

Okay this is the css code I put on the master page so it applies all the child page as well :

**Master.css**

```
a
{
  color:Red;
}

a:hover
{
  color:Blue;
}
```

and now on some pages I need to change color and hover color of the links like :

**Some child pages**

```
a
{
  color:Gray;
}

a:hover
{
  color:Maroon;
}
```

But the problem is it won't change the way I defined later. I used specific `id` and `class` approaches but they also don't work.

When I wanna change some specific element style, I use inline style attribute to do it but now `:hover` comes into play and I don't think I can declare it inline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS chooses between conflicting specifications by how specific the declaration is.

You can increase the specificity by specifying classes, ids, or adding `!important` to the end of your css declaration. For example:

```
a:hover
{
  color:Maroon;
}
```

will be overridden by

```
a.link:hover
{
  color:Blue;
}
```

will be overridden by

```
#link1:hover
{
  color:Red;
}
```

will be overridden by

```
a:hover
{
  color:Green !important ;
}
```

Comment: This one goes to my Favorites.

Answer (score 1):

*I used specific id and class approaches but they also don't work.*
Can you clarify?
Using specific selectors is the way to go. [An example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdsfr/).

There I define common `a` look for the whole page.

```
a {
  color:Red;
}
```

and custom style for specific areas where I want it to apply.

```
.new-look a {
  color: Gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your HTML markup is equally important.

```
a { color:red; }
a:hover { color:blue; }

a.foo { color:green; }
a.foo:hover { color:black; }

<a href="#">red</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">green</a>
```

will work, unless something else is at play.

or as the other post suggests ~

```
.foo a { color:red; }
#bar a:hover { color:blue; }
```

remember IDs take priority over classes.